# Is there a way to process file by detecting ACK files

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have an application and periodically files are coming in one folder.
There is always two files that comes, one is named ACK + Name of the file and is empty, and the other one is just the name of the file (this one is the data file).

I heard from some people that there is a way in Camel to process my file by detecting the ACK.

What I'm current doing is to detect the ACK file and then trigger a process that will get the data file and process it. But with this I can't have working unit test for my code.

But if it's possible I'd prefer to have a route that detect my ACK but trigger the process with the data file.

Is this possible ?

Here is my actual route:

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    public static final String ROUTE_NAME = "myRoute";

    private final Processor myProcessor;

    @Autowired
    public MyRoute(@Qualifier("my.processor") Processor myProcessor) {
        this.myProcessor= myProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("file://{{data.input.dir}}?moveFailed=errors&delete=true&include=ACK.*").routeId(ROUTE_NAME)
                .choice()
                    .when(header("CamelFileName").startsWith("ACK"))
                    .process(myProcessor)
                .end();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Found the solution using the `doneFileName` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out by yourself, Camel can handle this automatically with the `doneFileName` option.

You don't have to process the ACK file at all.

But as a consequence: if an ACK file is missing, the data file is not processed since Camel treats datafiles without done-file as still in process of transfer/writing.